# Have subdirectory with controllers in Kohana Framework

Tags: kohana, url-routing

Ok so it used to be in application/controller/classes/ where my controllers are.

Now i would like to have better structure, so i moved my user controllers to the user/ directory.

So this:

```
Route::set('user', 'user(/<action>)')
->defaults(array(
    'controller' => 'user',
    'action'     => 'index',
));
```

Got changed to:

```
Route::set('user', 'user(/<action>)')
->defaults(array(
    'directory'     => 'user',
    'controller' => 'user',
    'action'     => 'index',
));
```

Now i receive error, e.g user/login not found.

The controller for the above example, is in application/controller/classes/user/user.php.

I tried to remove the bottom default route just in case it was going through that, but no it still doesnt not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you changed name of your controller class? The directory name must be in the controllers name, in your case it should be Controller_User_User.

Comment: And application/controller/classes is wrong. Kohana 2.x used application/controllers, 3.x uses application/classes/controller. But since he marked this answer as the answer I assume he did not make that mistake in his actual filesystem.